# what does deg do in np.polyfit numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

```
x = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])

y = np.array([ 6, 3, 9, 5 , 4])

m , b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
```

how does the 1(deg) work in this linear regression? I do know it represents the degree of fitting the polynomial but how does it actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The degree-parameter n determines the polynimial equation used for fitting. The coefficients p in this formula are in descending powers, and the length of p is n+1

[image]

This formula is then fitted (in a [least-squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) sense) to the data.